# How to parse JSON data to field value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am pretty new to web programming. I have a function which fills the form field values on Select.

The Javascript code looks like below:

```
function loadTemplate(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var myTemplate = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("first_name").value = myTemplate.first_name;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "templates?id=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

The templates?id=22 page response looks like

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"profile": 1,
"first_name": "Robert",
"timestamp": "2019-12-14 00:00:00",
"ip": "127.0.0.1",
"status": 1
}
]
```

Now, I am trying to get the first_name value alone and fill in the form field whereas I am getting the entire JSON response.

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: That is an object in an array so `myTemplate[0].first_name`

Comment: In these situations you can use the browsers javascript debugger. Press F12 and you will find lots of useful resourses for a developer. One is a js debugger, so set a breakpoint on a line and then view the data that is returned

Comment: Wow. It worked. Thank you so much for  your quick help.

Answer (score 1):

The data is being returned as an array, you need to get the object at index 0 before you can access its properties, try:

```
document.getElementById("first_name").value = myTemplate[0].first_name;
```

Also, it may be worth checking the `mytemplate` HAS an element at index 0 (otherwise an error will occur if array is blank)